# AJAX Search functions differently in development/production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I added an instant search function to my app.

It works exactly as I want it to on the local server:

- Narrows list on keypress
- Case-agnostic
- Allows for reset (so if I type something and then delete it, the search is reset, and un-narrows). It allows for backtracking as well, so if I mistype and delete the mistyped letters, the search fixes accordingly.

In production, the behavior is totally weird. While it also does keypress search, it has a number of weird problems.

- It is case-sensitive (unlike in development) -- this isn't what I want.
- It behaves strangely as regards reset. If I type something like "instatn" and then correct the error, it doesn't redo the search. It also doesn't redo the search if I delete the whole entry. However, weirdly,
- If I delete the search term and then type a single letter, it resets the search.
- It doesn't seem to be searching correctly, period. If I type in "z", despite the fact that none of the items I'm searching through contain a "z", none of them disappear. On the other hand, if I type, say "Blogging", the list will in fact narrow to the two items with that word in their names.

Any idea what's going on here? Why are the two different? How can I fix it? Let me know what sort of code might help explain.

My code:

**archive.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag @post, :method => 'get', :id => "posts_search", class: "search_form squeeze form-inline" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], 
    placeholder: "Search titles:", id: "search_field" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn squeeze search" %>
  </p>
  <div id="list"><%= render 'search' %></div>
<% end %>
```

**_search.html.erb**

```
<ul class="blog_links">
<% @posts.first(@link_num).each do |p| %>
    <li class="total_hover">
        <%= p.name %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

**archive.js.erb**

```
$("#list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("search")) %>");
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
  def archive
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).reverse

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
      format.js
    end
  end

 def search
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).reverse
    render json: { results: @posts }
 end
```

**post.rb**

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

**javascripts/posts.js.coffee**

```
@search = ->
  $.get $('#posts_search').attr("action"), $("#posts_search").serialize(), null, "script"

$ ->
  $('#posts_search input').keypress -> search()

  $('#posts_search').submit (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    search()
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/search', to: 'posts#search'
match '/archive', to: 'posts#archive'
```

**EDIT** To provide some clues, I'm executing the same user behavior in both environments and posting the blogs. What I'll do is this:

1. Load the page containing the search.
2. Enter "Blgo"
3. Delete the "go" and replace it with "og"
4. Delete everything and search for "Insta"

**development logs**

```
Started GET "/archive" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:52 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as HTML
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (55.7ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.html.erb within layouts/application (57.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 72.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

# Cut out bootstrap loading etc for brevity

Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1362122453454" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:54 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"", "_"=>"1362122453454"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (13.2ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (14.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 16.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=b&_=1362122453455" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:54 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"b", "_"=>"1362122453455"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%b%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=b&_=1362122453456" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:54 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"b", "_"=>"1362122453456"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%b%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122453457" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:54 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"bl", "_"=>"1362122453457"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%bl%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122453458" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:55 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"bl", "_"=>"1362122453458"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%bl%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blg&_=1362122453459" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:55 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blg", "_"=>"1362122453459"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blg%')
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blg&_=1362122453460" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:55 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blg", "_"=>"1362122453460"}
  [1m[36mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blg%')[0m
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blgo&_=1362122453461" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:55 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blgo", "_"=>"1362122453461"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blgo%')
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blg&_=1362122453462" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:55 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blg", "_"=>"1362122453462"}
  [1m[36mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blg%')[0m
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122453463" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:55 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"bl", "_"=>"1362122453463"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%bl%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122453464" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:56 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"bl", "_"=>"1362122453464"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%bl%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blo&_=1362122453465" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:56 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blo", "_"=>"1362122453465"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blo%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 7.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blog&_=1362122453466" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:56 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blog", "_"=>"1362122453466"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blog%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (4.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blog&_=1362122453467" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:56 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blog", "_"=>"1362122453467"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blog%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blo&_=1362122453468" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:57 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blo", "_"=>"1362122453468"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%blo%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122453469" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:57 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"bl", "_"=>"1362122453469"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%bl%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=b&_=1362122453470" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:57 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"b", "_"=>"1362122453470"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%b%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1362122453471" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:58 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"", "_"=>"1362122453471"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (17.9ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (19.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 21.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1362122453472" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:58 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"", "_"=>"1362122453472"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (12.2ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (13.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 15.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=I&_=1362122453473" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:58 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"I", "_"=>"1362122453473"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%I%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (5.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 7.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

#... You get the picture. I went over character count. (!)

Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Insta&_=1362122453481" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-28 23:20:59 -0800
Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Insta", "_"=>"1362122453481"}
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (name LIKE '%Insta%')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

**heroku logs**

```
013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:21 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=43ms status=200 bytes=3343
2013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as HTML
2013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 5.2ms | ActiveRecord: 13.2ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.2ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)

2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1362122601827" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:24 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.5ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"", "_"=>"1362122601827"}
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (3.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 3.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)

2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=b&_=1362122601828" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:24 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"b", "_"=>"1362122601828"}
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (0.4ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=b&_=1362122601828 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=53
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1362122601827 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=198ms status=200 bytes=703

2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122601829" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:24 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"bl", "_"=>"1362122601829"}
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (0.4ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122601829 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=89ms status=200 bytes=53
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blg&_=1362122601830 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=53
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blg", "_"=>"1362122601830"}
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (0.4ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS

2013-03-01T07:23:24+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blg&_=1362122601830" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:24 +0000

2013-03-01T07:23:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122601831" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:27 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=bl&_=1362122601831 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=53
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"bl", "_"=>"1362122601831"}
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)

2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blo&_=1362122601832" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:28 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blo", "_"=>"1362122601832"}
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (0.3ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:28+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blo&_=1362122601832 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=61ms status=200 bytes=53

2013-03-01T07:23:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1362122601833" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:30 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (2.5ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"", "_"=>"1362122601833"}
2013-03-01T07:23:30+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (2.1ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:30+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1362122601833 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=703

2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=I&_=1362122601834" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:32 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=I&_=1362122601834 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=218
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 2.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"I", "_"=>"1362122601834"}
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.7ms)

2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=In&_=1362122601835" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:32 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"In", "_"=>"1362122601835"}
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.1ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=In&_=1362122601835 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=218

2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Ins&_=1362122601836" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:32 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Ins", "_"=>"1362122601836"}
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.0ms)

2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Inst&_=1362122601837" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:32 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Inst", "_"=>"1362122601837"}
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.1ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:32+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Inst&_=1362122601837 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=218

2013-03-01T07:23:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Insta&_=1362122601838" for 69.181.104.85 at 2013-03-01 07:23:33 +0000
2013-03-01T07:23:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#archive as JS
2013-03-01T07:23:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Insta", "_"=>"1362122601838"}
2013-03-01T07:23:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/archive.js.erb (1.0ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_search.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-03-01T07:23:33+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Insta&_=1362122601838 host=<my_site>.com fwd="69.181.104.85" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=218
```

Again, while the development search worked perfectly and as I think generally to-be-expected, in production, what happened with the above was: the list narrowed until I typed the g in "blg", at which point there were no more list items. When I deleted the "go" and typed "og", the list did NOT re-expand to incorporate items with "blog" in the title. Nor did it incorporate everything when I deleted all the letters in the search box.

The search reset only when I typed "I", and because Instant is, in fact, a term in the list, it narrowed down to the one item the name of which contained "Insta".

So, weird. Any ideas what's up here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (the disjunction) ended up just being a database problem.

I was running sqlite development and postgresql production, and the two responded differently to my search method. When I switched development to pg, the search was equally broken in both environments, and I decided to use Thinking Sphinx instead of a homebrewed solution.